# How to find out more about encrypted partitions?

Tags: 10.04, partitioning, encryption, lvm

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 with the alternate CD. I'm using a encrypte LVM. So all my partitions should be encrypted.
But how do I find out, if they are encrypted and how (AES?, bit?,...)

Thanks for help...
Sam

Answer (score 1):

LUKS, which ubuntu uses to handle encryption, provides a way to check if a partition is a LUKS partition.

```
sudo cryptsetup isLuks [device]
```

The result is stored in the command's exit status. You can then use normal bash logic to find out the result. For example:

```
sudo cryptsetup isLuks /dev/sda2 && echo "Yes, it is LUKS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `.ecryptfs` directory in the root directory of each volume. Try `df -h`. Here's what I get (encrypted `/home/walt`, unencrypted everything else):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             163G   15G  141G  10% /
udev                  2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 791M  1.2M  790M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  2.0G  132K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6             289G  113G  162G  41% /home
df: `/home/walt/.gvfs': Transport endpoint is not connected
/home/walt/.Private   289G  113G  162G  41% /home/walt
```

Oh yes, since we are looking for "hidden" files, be sure to use "`-a`" or "`-A`" on your `ls` command.

Comment: What should we look for in the output of `df -h`? What `ls` command? The OP is using dm-crypt, LUKS and LVM, not ecryptfs.